# How can I click on link by using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to catch an onclick on our intranet. I haven't got far in my code and I don't know how I can do it and then proceed to get info from the webpage. I have this from our intranet:

```
innerHTML                    : <TD class=ms-gb noWrap colSpan=100><A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('7111-2_', 'img_7111-2_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:"><IMG id=img_7111
                           -2_ alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" border=0>&nbsp;HW Status</A> : EOL HW<SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: lighter; DISPLAY: inline-block">&nbsp;‎(47) </SPAN
                           ></TD>
innerText                    :  HW Status : EOL HW ‎(47) 
outerHTML                    : 
                           <TR id=group0><TD class=ms-gb noWrap colSpan=100><A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('7111-2_', 'img_7111-2_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:"><I
                           MG id=img_7111-2_ alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" border=0>&nbsp;HW Status</A> : EOL HW<SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: lighter; DISPLAY: inline-block">&nbs
                           p;‎(47) </SPAN></TD></TR>
outerText                    :  HW Status : EOL HW ‎(47)
```

This is my code:

```
Clear-Host
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://share.mycompany.org/tools/desktopmanagement/Lists/Standard%20PC%   20Hardware/HW%20Status.aspx" -UseDefaultCredentials
$Rows = ($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td") | Where{ $_.className -eq 'ms-gb' } ).innerHTML
foreach($Row in $Rows) {
    $Row
}
```

This is my output $Row

```
<A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('860-1_', 'img_860-1_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:"><IMG id=img_860-1_ alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" border=0>&nbsp;HW Status</A> : Approved Model<SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: lighter; DISPLAY: inline-block">&nbsp;‎(36) </SPAN>
<A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('860-2_', 'img_860-2_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:"><IMG id=img_860-2_ alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" border=0>&nbsp;HW Status</A> : EOL HW<SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: lighter; DISPLAY: inline-block">&nbsp;‎(47) </SPAN
```

I hope that is enough

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't, directly, not for Javascript.

Javascript is executed by the *client-side* browser program: Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome et al. Therefore, in order to execute it, you need to make the click from within a browser.

Powershell can set up form variables and pass them to *server-side* processing by calling HTTP requests, but in order to parse the page and execute client-side JavaScript, you need some Javascript-aware HTML parser. Namely -- a browser.

What is generally done in such situations is akin to [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) where a specialized browser program -- typically headless version of chrome/firefox or a more specialized browser, is ran for the needed page, and you program it with info, which mouseclicks/keyboard events to simulate.

There are separate libraries which allow integrating web scraping into general programming languages. You can perhaps utilize it and steer it from Powershell, but in any case it *is* another layer between PS and the webpage without which you can't do it, afaik.

Alternative would be to reprogram the relevant webpage Javscript functions (such as ExpCollGroup in your example) in Powershell, but it will likely need extra info from webpage, which might be hard to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm of track here of how webpages behave, but what I'm trying to succeed is to search for "Dell Optiplex 7010" and pick this text "30/07/2017". The reason for the topic name is that I can't see the below source on the webpage when I load the page for the first time. So I was little unsure if the below source only exists if I pressed a link. I found the below source by pressing F12 in IE.

```
<TR class=ms-itmhover iid="7043,4,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
<TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT title="Dell Optiplex 7010&#13;&#10;  " class=s4-itm-cbx type=checkbox value="" _setup="true"></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2>Desktop</TD>
<TD height="100%" class=ms-vb-title onmouseover=OnChildItem(this)>
<DIV class="ms-vb itx" id=4 onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0xb008431061" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx7043"><A onclick="EditLink2(this,7043);return false;" onfocus=OnLink(this) href="http://share.intranet.org/tools/desktopmanagement/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={5696DF31-E236-4F3F-8EE2-90707DADC0EA}&amp;ID=4&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100FA254EECE740F54DA0D1B9E62EEDBB94" target=_self>Dell Optiplex 7010</A></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx style="HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 830px; MARGIN: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 25px; TOP: 112px" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;" shown="false"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" href="javascript:;"><IMG width=7 height=4 style="VISIBILITY: hidden" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2>EOL HW</TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2><NOBR>01/07/2012</NOBR></TD>
<TD class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell"><NOBR>30/07/2017</NOBR></TD></TR>
```

Comment: It either exists or is created on the fly after you click. If it is created in the fly, my answer stands. If it exists, then you can extract it via powershell and some command line utility that, for example, let's you select parts of page via XPath or similar queries. I haven't tried it, but I read good reviews of Microsoft Log parser, for example : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659